# Scala won't let me sort string array

Tags: scala, sorting, compiler-errors

I have defined the following object which I want to sort a string concurrently.

```
object QuoteFuture extends App {

  val wordsStr : String = "Lorem ipsum dolor ..."

  import scala.concurrent._
  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val f : Future[String] = Future {
    val wordsArr = wordsStr.split("\\s+")
    wordsArr.sorted // <<<<< Compiler error from here (line 15)
  }
  f.onComplete(t => {
    if (t.isSuccess) {
      println(s"words sorted: ${t.get}")
    } else {
      println("could not sort words")
    }
  })
}
```

I have omitted the entire string for brevity. When I attempt to run the code above, I get the following compilation error:

```
Error:(15, 14) polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [B >: String]Array[String]
 required: String
    wordsArr.sorted
```

I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared your future `f` to be of type `String`, but `wordsArr.sorted` is going to be an `Array[String]`, so you should declare it as

```
val f : Future[Array[String]] = //...
```